# Rxjs angular 6/7 mergeMap delay http request

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs6

I want to send request using this code (i've tried forkJoin too) with a delay between calls:

```
duplicateElement(id: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get({ routeName: 'route_name', params: { id } });
}

duplicateElements(ids: string[]): Observable<any> {
    return from(ids)
    .pipe(
        mergeMap(id => this.duplicateElement(id).pipe(delay(1000))
    ));
}
```

but .pipe(delay(1000) is not working how I expect: send each http request after 1000 mls.

Comment: How do you expect it to work?

Comment: I want to send each http request with a delay of 1000 mls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Now two alternatives!

### Basic setup

```
import * as rx from "rxjs";
import * as rxop from "rxjs/operators";

const startTime = new Date();

function getTimestamp() {
  return (new Date().getTime() - startTime.getTime()) / 1000;
}


const desiredDelay = 750;
const serviceDelay = 500;

// simulating service, you can ignore what's inside
var myService = (b: any) => {
  return rx.of(Math.random()).pipe(
    // To simulate long running service
    rxop.delay(serviceDelay),
    // Log the timestap after execution, should be ~ desiredDelay + serviceDelay, so by default 1250ms each emitted value
    rxop.tap(() => console.log(`${b} after service result, ${getTimestamp()}`)),
    // simulating the result
    rxop.map(a => "result" + b)
  );
};
```

### Emit values one by one after a delay, execute service and collect the result as soon as possible

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .pipe(
    // See the initial values
    tap(console.log),
    // Split array into single values during emit
    // Collect observables and subscribe to next when previous completes
    concatAll(),
    // Emit each value as a sequence of observables with a desired delay
    concatMap(a => of(a).pipe(delay(desiredDelay))),
    // Call service on each value as soon as possible, do not care about the order
    mergeMap(a => myService(a)),
    // Reduce single values back into array
    // Reduces the values from source observable to a single value that's emitted when the source completes
    reduce<any>((acc, val) => [...acc, val], []),
    // See the result, not necessary
    tap(console.log)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

### Call service on a value, wait a delay, then call service with another value

```
of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
  .pipe(
    // See the initial values
    tap(console.log),
    // Split array into single values during emit
    // Collect observables and subscribe to next when previous completes
    concatAll(),
    // Call the service
    // Map values to inner observable, subscribe and emit in order
    concatMap(a => myService(a).pipe(delay(desiredDelay))),
    // Reduce single values back into array
    // Reduces the values from source observable to a single value that's emitted when the source completes
    reduce<any>((acc, val) => [...acc, val], []),
    // See the result, not necessary
    tap(console.log)
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Thank you Jacek, but this way sends all request after 1000mls, but i would like send one request by id every 1000 mls

Comment: try this one. If this does not work, I'll be able to give you better results when I'm actually before my PC :) `return from(unitIds).pipe(
    switchMap(id => this.duplicateElement(id).pipe(
    delay(1000))),
    concatAll()
);`

Comment: Thanks Jacek! Great explanation and example. But we need to use mergeMap because we would like the requests to be "pseudo" (with a delay) parallel, using concatMap, I think they are sequential.

Comment: Updated. Please note, that when firing simultaneously it's way harder to actually preserve the call order. I'd rather suggest on slightly different idea if you'd need a certain call order

Comment: Awesome examples! In our case, order is not important, so it works great...thank you very much Jacek!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
duplicateElements(ids: string[]): Observable<any> {
    return interval(1000).pipe( // start emitting every 1000ms
        take(ids.length),  // limit emissions to length of array
        map(i => ids[i]),  // map (change) emission to the array item @ index i 
        mergeMap(id => this.duplicateElement(id)) // add the http request
    )
}
```

Comment: Hmmm ... what about it doesn't work?  I did think of one addition that is needed ... I will update the answer with `take(ids.length)` so that interval stops emitting after the correct number of tries.  Also, do you want each subsequent http call to REPLACE the previous http call, or do you want it to ADD another http call?  mergeMap will keep building them up but it you want to replace them then switchMap might be a better choice.

Comment: Thanks, great!, Yes, you're right ... it was sent undefined after the correct number of attempts